# General Questions about Copyright and iOS 11 Warnings due to old Frameworks

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

1. How is it with the copyright? For example I have linked a button to a Facebook page in my App and on the Button I've put a small image of the Facebook Icon, where do I have to mention the copyrights?
   And Code copied from Stacksocial doesn't have copyright?
2. I have some really small Images in my App, is it important to convert them for 2x 3x ? for example: 
   https://imgur.com/a/88p8E
3. With the new release of Xcode 9 and ios 11 I have a warning: update to recommend setting. And I tried but it destroyed my App because the frameworks needed to update as well. Can I ignore the Warning? Because the App works just fine on ios 11.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Furthermore, it has certain guidelines concerning what a question should look like and what is on-topic. Read [ask].

Comment: This is an inappropriate question for SO. SO is about solving specific programming, coding and technical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If unsure how to deal with copyright, a lawyer is your best friend.  A 1hr consultation should be more than enough to give you an introductory tour of this world and make you feel at ease.  Highly recommended if you have no clue what are you getting into.  A good online resource to get to know what the different typical open source licenses are and what they mean is [Licenses & Standard | Open Source Initiative](https://opensource.org/licenses)
2. It is typically a good idea to provide all pixel density images, if you don't have them or want to easily generate the various images, there's a good tool on the Mac App Store named [AssetsProcessor](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/assets-processor/id1240024311?mt=12)
3. You should typically apply the update to your project but not to the framework.  That does mean that you will have build warnings; something you have to learn to live with until you feel comfortable branching off the different frameworks and updating them yourself.  Overall yes, learning which warnings are safe to ignore and which ones should be addressed is important.  There's no magic here, except TEST, TEST and TEST to ensure that ignoring a warning won't be the death of your app.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped me! Have a nice day! :)